# Can I force GWT to leave out default CSS classes?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm tired of all the superfluous crap GWT renders into my HTML. Is there a setting I can turn on/off to prevent GWT from adding its default css classes on elements?

I want to get rid of things like class="gwt-RadioButton" and class="gwt-InlineLabel" from the rendered HTML. I don't use their themes so all it does is add unnecessary bloat.

Comment: You can override css styles with your own with setStyleName().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

IIRC, it was suggested a long time ago but no one took the time to do it. Particularly as it apparent doesn't have a big impact in performance (either output size or runtime perf)

Comment: Oh well, maybe in some future version. I know I'm just being obsessive but it just drives me nuts. I guess if I were really that bothered by it I could just wrap every element that I use and override it.